# Having problems exporting model functions (Express and Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have been looking at code (https://github.com/cmarin/MongoDB-Node-Express-Blog) to learn NodeJS, Express, Mongoose, and I am having trouble importing a 'Poll' function from my 'models.js' file, particularly the 'save' function.

I am getting the following error:

```
500 TypeError: Object function (){} has no method 'save'
```

It occurs on line 54 of my app.js. I am unable to save a new Poll because it cannot find the function:
https://github.com/kelper/Poll/blob/master/app.js

Here is my models file, and the save function is on line 62:
https://github.com/kelper/Poll/blob/master/models.js

One other quick question. How can I exclude files from being committed? I keep committing swap files and such to my repo.

If you see anything else wrong with my code, please tell me. I know one person mentioned that my naming conventions are confusing. How should I be naming my variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PollModel is a function constructor, you want to create an object.

`var PollModel = require('./models').PollModel;` is wrong

`var pollModel = new (require('./models').PollModel);` is right.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you've got a proxy object built up using prototype. In this case you're going to have to 'new up' an instance to use it as Raynos mentioned.

I think what you're expecting is what an object literal provides, rather than a prototypical class. Something like:

```
module.exports.PollModel = {
  findPolls  : function (callback) { ... },
  findById   : function (id, callback) { ... },
  updateById : function (id, body, callback) { ... }
}
```

I'd personally use the mongoose schema directly.

Mongoose uses the Schema object to do queries for that particular model, but if you actually want to create and save new objects of that schema type, you want to new up a new object.

```
// Assume you've exposed the mongoose Poll schema directly
var Poll = require('./models').Poll;

// Create a new instance
var instance = new Poll();

// Valid
instance.save();

// Not valid
instance.find(function(err, docs){});

// Valid
Poll.find(function(err, docs){});

// Not valid
Poll.save();
```

Comment: PollModel is not a mongoose schema. It's just a poorly named variable

Comment: So it is, https://github.com/kelper/Poll/blob/master/models.js#L31 - good catch. I'll edit.

Comment: Hello, how should I be naming the variables in my models.js? I guess I shouldn't be calling it the PollModel, since the Poll is actually a model. What should I be calling my PollModel? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Its only confusing because you said 'problems exporting model functions using mongoose' -- i assumed PollModel was a mongoose Schema. You can name it whatever you want imo, though like i mentioned, i'd have expected you to use the Schema directly for queries

Comment: Do you recommend following this structure: https://github.com/alessioalex/Nodetuts/blob/master/mongodb_mongoose/example.js? I am not sure what convention to follow. I am in the hacky phase right now, so I don't want to get caught up in the small details while learning.

Comment: Looks good to me. I usually export module.export =  mongoose.model('Post'); Then wherever I need it, i'll require('post')

Comment: They declare a static function to get the most recent posts. Is the static function like static functions from other programming languages? If I have a dedicated schemas.js, and I import the file into index.js, will I be able to access the recent function?

Comment: The 'static' functions you mentioned like .findOne are available on the model function constructor. They're defined as Model.methodName as opposed to Model.prototype.methodName more than likely, so you can use them without 'new.' This is trickery you don't see very often in javascript